# Can't make php conditional "if" work inside HTML

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements, php-ini

my code is the following;

```
            <select class="reg_field_field" id="user_address_state" name="user_address_state" tabindex="7">
                <option value="AL" <?php if($state=='AL') echo 'selected';?>/>Alabama</option>
                <option value="AK" <?php if($state=='AK') echo 'selected';?>/>Alaska</option>
                <option value="AZ" <?php if($state=='AZ') echo 'selected';?>/>Arizona</option>
         ....       
            </select>
```

And the result is showing me instead the state name, it show "Notice: Undefined variable...".

I tried this in other server and worked, could be the php.ini configuration???
What can be on php.ini?

Thank you for any help

Ale

Comment: Did your other server have `register_globals` enabled? This isn't all your code. Please post the PHP code where `$state` is set.

Comment: *please* use a [for loop or something](http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for this.

Answer (score 6):

The error tells you the problem: `$state` is undefined. You need to examine your code to determine where `$state` should be defined and ensure that it is being set properly.

If you are attempting to save user input to the `$state` variable, look for a line like:

```
$state = $_POST['user_address_state'];
```

If it does not exist, create it prior to the lines you included in your post.

Comment: Is defined inside the php "<?php if($state=='AL') echo 'selected';?>/>Alabama" and they will tell me what is option was selected by the entry

Comment: the complete error say "Notice: Undefined variable: state in C:\server\www\myweb\form.php on line 101 />Alabama..." and all the state names  on screen to be ready to select. The form is working but instead appearing only the state name, show this error

Comment: The statement `if($state=='AL')` does not define `$state`. It merely compares the value of state to a string ('AL'). If `$state` is not explicitly defined before that line, you will see the error.

Answer (score 0):

does $state have a default value? It has to have a value prior to checking to see if it matches against another.